# Perl: modules colliding when both import the same module

Tags: perl, module, namespaces, package

Let's say I have two modules, A and Bee, each of which uses a third mod, Shared.

A:

```
package A;
BEGIN {
    use Shared;
    use Bee;
}

sub new {
    my ($class) = @_;
    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;
    $self->B(Bee->new);
    $self;
}

sub B {
    my($self, $B) = @_;
    $self->{b} = $B if defined $B;
    $self->{b};
}

sub test {
    shared_sub();
}
```

Bee:

```
package Bee;

BEGIN {
    use Shared;
}

sub new {
    my ($class) = @_;
    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;
    $self;
}

sub test {
    shared_sub();
}

1;
```

Shared (note that it doesn't declare a package name):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
BEGIN {
    require Exporter;

    our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
    our @EXPORT_OK = qw(shared_sub);
}

sub shared_sub {
    print "This is the shared sub in package '" . __PACKAGE__ . "'\n";
}

1;
```

From the script that calls A:

```
use A;
my $A = A->new;
$A->test;       # This is the shared sub in package 'A'
$A->B->test;    # Undefined subroutine &Bee::shared_sub called at Bee.pm line 19.
```

From the script that calls Bee only:

```
use Bee;
my $B = Bee->new;
$B->test;   # This is the shared sub in package 'Bee'
```

Individually, both A and Bee can invoke the test() method without error, but when I nest Bee in A, that's when, all of a sudden, Bee can't find the Shared method anymore; isn't it imported into the namespace of whatever module calls it?

The obvious answer is to give Shared its own package name and then update all the modules that use it, but I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid doing that with an easier solution.

Answer (score 4):

Only use `require` (and thus `use`) with modules (files with a `package`). Use `do` otherwise. If you don't, you get this problem.

`require` only executed a file once, yet you need to run it once each module that use it.

Modules only get executed once, but you are expecting the code to be executed every time you do `use Shared;`

> *Bee can't find the Shared method anymore*

`Shared` never has any methods. No such namespace is every created.

> *The obvious answer is to give Shared its own package name and then update all the modules that use it,*

You don't have to update any files except `Shared.pm`.

Comment: ikegami, can you clarify a few things? First, I assume that to use `do`, I simply code, `do Module.pm`, similar to `require`ing or `use`ing a module, yes? Second, you say that the only file I need to change is `Shared.pm`, but then, that's not the file that has the `do Module.pm`, correct? Unless I'm mistaken...

Comment: @Lee Wang, Cause you shouldn't switch to `do`. You should add the missing `package`.